# can’t symetrize my mesh

Tags: sculpting

Hi so I started to use dynotopo on my object or character. I realized it hadn’t been mirroring well. Or hasn’t overall. So some parts are off, I tried to snap to symmetry on edit mode. Ends up with 4494 mirrored, and 84012 failed. I then tried to do dynotopo symetrize. I tried all of the directions, for example -x to +x, and vice versa. I also tried all of the rest and they all end up wonky, like two heads beside each other or inside each other. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: tip: press ⌘+SHIFT+3 to take a quick screenshot on mac

Comment: Hi. This may help with taking clearer screenshots: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org